# Forwarding messages between the opposite gender without actually taking to them

Tags: non-mahram, friendship

I had a fried of the opposite sex for a very long time and I decided I would try to end things with them since it's haram. It didn't go very well and we both got very emotional and couldn't let go so we decided that I would talk to someone of the same sex and that person would forward online messages between us. I have a feeling like that's also haram but I just don't know how to convince them to let go of this friendship. I'm also struggling to let go of this friendship and I don't know how to completely stop thinking about it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I fixed it now I hope it makes sense

Comment: maybe private messages are kharam but public messages are khalal, so you can talk in a public chat? but i do not know any web service where many people are registered, like social network or messenger, so that your relatives and friends can subscribe to the public discussion, that allows only public posts with no private message link, and do not allow to delete or edit your posts, so that it is not possible to post private message contact address and quickly delete it. so seems this is a good idea to create such web service...